# How to update the learning rate in a two layered multi-layered perceptron?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, deep-learning, xor

Given the XOR problem:

```
X = xor_input = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]])
Y = xor_output = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T
```

And a simple

- two layered Multi-Layered Perceptron (MLP) with
- sigmoid activations between them and
- Mean Square Error (MSE) as the loss function/optimization criterion

[code]:

```
def sigmoid(x): # Returns values that sums to one.
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(sx): # For backpropagation.
    # See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1225116
    return sx * (1 - sx)

# Cost functions.
def mse(predicted, truth):
    return np.sum(np.square(truth - predicted))

X = xor_input = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]])
Y = xor_output = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T

# Define the shape of the weight vector.
num_data, input_dim = X.shape
# Lets set the dimensions for the intermediate layer.
hidden_dim = 5
# Initialize weights between the input layers and the hidden layer.
W1 = np.random.random((input_dim, hidden_dim))

# Define the shape of the output vector. 
output_dim = len(Y.T)
# Initialize weights between the hidden layers and the output layer.
W2 = np.random.random((hidden_dim, output_dim))
```

And given the stopping criteria as a fixed no. of epochs (no. of iterations through the X and Y) with a fixed learning rate of 0.3:

```
# Initialize weigh
num_epochs = 10000
learning_rate = 0.3
```

When I run through the forward-backward propagation and update the weights in each epoch, **how should I update the weights?**

I tried to simply add the product of the learning rate with the dot product of the backpropagated derivative with the layer outputs but the model still only updated the weights in one direction causing all the weights to degrade to near zero.

```
for epoch_n in range(num_epochs):
    layer0 = X
    # Forward propagation.

    # Inside the perceptron, Step 2. 
    layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer0, W1))
    layer2 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer1, W2))

    # Back propagation (Y -> layer2)

    # How much did we miss in the predictions?
    layer2_error = mse(layer2, Y)

    #print(layer2_error)
    # In what direction is the target value?
    # Were we really close? If so, don't change too much.
    layer2_delta = layer2_error * sigmoid_derivative(layer2)

    # Back propagation (layer2 -> layer1)
    # How much did each layer1 value contribute to the layer2 error (according to the weights)?
    layer1_error = np.dot(layer2_delta, W2.T)
    layer1_delta = layer1_error * sigmoid_derivative(layer1)

    # update weights
    W2 += - learning_rate * np.dot(layer1.T, layer2_delta)
    W1 += - learning_rate * np.dot(layer0.T, layer1_delta)
    #print(np.dot(layer0.T, layer1_delta))
    #print(epoch_n, list((layer2)))

    # Log the loss value as we proceed through the epochs.
    losses.append(layer2_error.mean())
```

**How should the weights be updated correctly?**

Full code:

```
from itertools import chain
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

def sigmoid(x): # Returns values that sums to one.
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(sx):
    # See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1225116
    return sx * (1 - sx)

# Cost functions.
def mse(predicted, truth):
    return np.sum(np.square(truth - predicted))

X = xor_input = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]])
Y = xor_output = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T

# Define the shape of the weight vector.
num_data, input_dim = X.shape
# Lets set the dimensions for the intermediate layer.
hidden_dim = 5
# Initialize weights between the input layers and the hidden layer.
W1 = np.random.random((input_dim, hidden_dim))

# Define the shape of the output vector. 
output_dim = len(Y.T)
# Initialize weights between the hidden layers and the output layer.
W2 = np.random.random((hidden_dim, output_dim))

# Initialize weigh
num_epochs = 10000
learning_rate = 0.3

losses = []

for epoch_n in range(num_epochs):
    layer0 = X
    # Forward propagation.

    # Inside the perceptron, Step 2. 
    layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer0, W1))
    layer2 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer1, W2))

    # Back propagation (Y -> layer2)

    # How much did we miss in the predictions?
    layer2_error = mse(layer2, Y)

    #print(layer2_error)
    # In what direction is the target value?
    # Were we really close? If so, don't change too much.
    layer2_delta = layer2_error * sigmoid_derivative(layer2)

    # Back propagation (layer2 -> layer1)
    # How much did each layer1 value contribute to the layer2 error (according to the weights)?
    layer1_error = np.dot(layer2_delta, W2.T)
    layer1_delta = layer1_error * sigmoid_derivative(layer1)

    # update weights
    W2 += - learning_rate * np.dot(layer1.T, layer2_delta)
    W1 += - learning_rate * np.dot(layer0.T, layer1_delta)
    #print(np.dot(layer0.T, layer1_delta))
    #print(epoch_n, list((layer2)))

    # Log the loss value as we proceed through the epochs.
    losses.append(layer2_error.mean())

# Visualize the losses
plt.plot(losses)
plt.show()
```

**Am I missing anything in the backpropagation?**

**Maybe I missed out the derivative from the cost to the second layer?**

---

## Edited

I realized I missed the partial derivative from the cost to the second layer and after adding it:

```
# Cost functions.
def mse(predicted, truth):
    return 0.5 * np.sum(np.square(predicted - truth)).mean()

def mse_derivative(predicted, truth):
    return predicted - truth
```

With the updated backpropagation loop across epochs:

```
for epoch_n in range(num_epochs):
    layer0 = X
    # Forward propagation.

    # Inside the perceptron, Step 2. 
    layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer0, W1))
    layer2 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer1, W2))

    # Back propagation (Y -> layer2)

    # How much did we miss in the predictions?
    cost_error = mse(layer2, Y)
    cost_delta = mse_derivative(layer2, Y)

    #print(layer2_error)
    # In what direction is the target value?
    # Were we really close? If so, don't change too much.
    layer2_error = np.dot(cost_delta, cost_error)
    layer2_delta = layer2_error *  sigmoid_derivative(layer2)

    # Back propagation (layer2 -> layer1)
    # How much did each layer1 value contribute to the layer2 error (according to the weights)?
    layer1_error = np.dot(layer2_delta, W2.T)
    layer1_delta = layer1_error * sigmoid_derivative(layer1)

    # update weights
    W2 += - learning_rate * np.dot(layer1.T, layer2_delta)
    W1 += - learning_rate * np.dot(layer0.T, layer1_delta)
```

It seemed to train and learn the XOR...

But now the question begets, is the `layer2_error` and `layer2_delta` computed correctly, i.e. **is the following part of the code correct?**

```
# How much did we miss in the predictions?
cost_error = mse(layer2, Y)
cost_delta = mse_derivative(layer2, Y)

#print(layer2_error)
# In what direction is the target value?
# Were we really close? If so, don't change too much.
layer2_error = np.dot(cost_delta, cost_error)
layer2_delta = layer2_error *  sigmoid_derivative(layer2)
```

**Is it correct to do a dot product on the `cost_delta` and `cost_error` for the `layer2_error`? Or would `layer2_error` just be equals to `cost_delta`?**

I.e.

```
# How much did we miss in the predictions?
cost_error = mse(layer2, Y)
cost_delta = mse_derivative(layer2, Y)

#print(layer2_error)
# In what direction is the target value?
# Were we really close? If so, don't change too much.
layer2_error = cost_delta
layer2_delta = layer2_error *  sigmoid_derivative(layer2)
```

Comment: If the edited update routine that includes the cost derivatives is correct, then it looks very different from what I'll get if I use autogradient libraries like `pytorch`, see https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-should-weights-be-updated-in-multi-layered-perceptron/34967

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct to multiply the residuals (`cost_error`) with the delta values when we update the weights.

However, it doesn't really matter whether do dot product or not since it `cost_error` is a scalar. So, a simple multiplication is enough. But, we definitely have to multiply the gradient of the cost function because that's where we start our backprop (i.e. it's the entry point for backward pass).

Also, the below function can be simplified:

```
def mse(predicted, truth):
    return 0.5 * np.sum(np.square(predicted - truth)).mean()
```

as

```
def mse(predicted, truth):
    return 0.5 * np.mean(np.square(predicted - truth))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @kmario23 for confirming that it's right =)